# ActiveRecord: count is wrong after saving data in a new thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

I have a Rails app that do something like this (it's simplified for this example):

```
count = MyModel.count
t = Thread.new do
  m = MyModel.new
  // set data on m
  m.save
end
t.join
new_count = MyModel.count
```

Although the new record is being created, `new_count` is always the same as `count`. If I check it inside the thread, after saving, it is correct (count + 1).

What's the problem? How can I get the correct total after exiting the thread?

---

Edit: I got it working by setting the Rspec option `config.use_transactional_fixtures` to **false**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting the Rspec option `config.use_transactional_fixtures` to **false** in the 'spec_helper.rb' file.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
new_count = MyModel.uncached{ MyModel.count}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I also  tried `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache` and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_query_cache!` as suggested on other sites, but still nothing.

Comment: When I tried your code, I didnt encounter the issue. I suspect your save must be failing. Add log statement inside the thread after the save to check the save status (E.g.: Add `puts m.errors.to_xml` after `m.save`)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working by setting RSpec's `config.use_transactional_fixtures` to false.